# Python: How to exit all the recursions in a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Consider the following code:

```
def recursive():
    if condition1:
        return
    if condition2:
        recursive()
    if condition3:
        recursive()

recursive()
```

As you see in the Python Code above... The function returns if `condition1` checks or calls itself for `condition2` and `condition3`.
I want to exit all the recursions if the `condition1` is true.

**More explanation:**
Consider a scenario, where I call the function, it checks for `condition1`, let it be `false` in this case, hence it moves to `condition2`, which is `true` in this case, and hence the function calls itself. Now when the function calls itself, it again checks `condition1` but this time, let the condition be `true`, so the function ends and we get back to the old function which goes on checking for `condition3` and act accordingly.
My use case is to end all the recursions when the `condition1` is `true`... In the illustration I just told, when the second function calls passes the `condition1`, it returns back to the old function, but I want that it to not only end the particular recursion, but all the recursions that were made, just come to an end.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't do this literally without doing something like throwing an exception that you catch outside of the recursive function (I don't recommend that approach though). You'd be better off just making the returns back to the initial call happen naturally, like by making the `if`s into `elif`s.

Comment: At any rate, you need to exit the `recursion()` function calls since they are on your stack.

If you just don't want to continue with `condition3` as described in your example you can prevent this from happening in many ways, for example, by returning `bool` by `recursion()` function and do something like `if recursive(): return` for the first recursive call.

Comment: Thanks @radof... That is the best possible solution for my use case!